# Load testing server with http multipart/related request which contains audio content

Tags: apachebench

We built a server which handles speech recorded by user using an app. The audio data is sent through http post in real time. The body looks like this:

```
--BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"
Content-Type: application/json; charset="UTF-8"
<JSON FORMATTED METADATA HERE>
--BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="audio"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
<AUDIO BYTES HERE>
--BOUNDARY--
```

Now, I need to do load testing for the server. I am thinking of using ApacheBench and just do consistent uploading requests but I wish to use the same format as above for each request. How could that be setup in AB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by using the following command:

```
ab -p test -T "multipart/form-data; boundary=BOUNDARY" -c 1000 -n 1000 -l http://someipaddress.com/
```

where `test` is a file containing the post content.